# Regex match all characters except ".js"

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to separate a module name from it's path, with javascript. The string I am receiving the regex on may or may not have ".js" on the end, but in the 2nd matching group I need to not have the ".js" if it is there. This is the regular expression so far:

```
([\.\/]?.+\/)?(.+[\.js]?)
```

for example if I have the string: ./piechart.js

Match group 1: ./

Match group 2: piechart

More test/example: https://regex101.com/r/nL9lK3/1

Comment: The regex tag description pretty clearly says that when you use it, you should also add a tag that indicates what programming language or tool you are using because the syntax and functionality varies between them. While it may be safe to assume that because you're dealing with the .js extension you're using Javascript, you should add a tag to make it clear and to make it easier for future users to find.

Comment: Thanks, I've added javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So try this

`(\/?.+\/)*(.+?)(\.js)?$`

and use the first two matching groups only (here's the updated [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nL9lK3/5)).

**First group:** `(\/?.+\/)*` matches all the possible paths, ending in a final slash.

**Second group:** `(.+?)` matches everything following the path, but with a lazy quantifier, allowing the third group to match if it can.

**Third group:** `(\.js)?` matches a possible `.js` at the end of the string.

Comment: This isn't quite what I need. I want the path to the module to be in the first matching group, and the module name to be in the second matching grouop. If there is a ".js" at the end, it shouldn't be in any captured match group.

Comment: @sicter: ah, got it! I missed that. Check my update.

Comment: Perfect, I just made one quick change and made the third group a non-capturing match group: https://regex101.com/r/nL9lK3/6

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to filter the string first, then regex it to retrieve the module name.

```
function getModule (filePath) {
    var arr = filePath.split('/');
    var len = arr.length;

    var path = arr.splice(0, arr.length - 1).join('/');
    var moduleName = arr[0].match(/([a-zA-Z\-\_]+)(?=(\.js)?)/gi)[0];

    return [path, moduleName];
}
```

This function will return an array of `path` and `moduleName`.

Comment: Very clean approach! Note that `\w` does not match hyphens. So with a filename like `hello-world.js` this regex would just return `"hello"`. Changing the regex to `/([\w-]+)(?=(\.js)?)/gi` would work, though.

Comment: @MildlySerious Tq for noticing that. I just realized the OP also wants  to get the path. I hope this solves it.

Comment: This is similar to the path I was originally heading down, but a purely regex solution is more what I was looking for. This is answer may be useful for others though +1